# Not found Value && in spark dataframe: While comparing null Values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Hi I have 2 Dataframes df1 and df2 i m joining these 2 dataframe based on id column then creating one new column as result and checking below test conditions.
  1. If  name is same in both the cases then need to set as Y.
  but in case if any null is there in any dataframe or if null is there in both the column then it is showing not matched. I want if null is there in both the dataframe then it should take as matched so i have added below condition

```
    ||(df1("name") is null && df2("name") is null
```

so if both the column are null then it should print as matched but its showing  "Not found value'&&'" . I am writing below code. can someone plese suggest how should i implement this.

```
     df1.join(df2,df2("id") === df2("id"))
     .withColumn("Result", when(df1("name") === df2("name") ||
     (df1("name") is null && 
     (df2("name") is null," matched"))
     .otherwise(" Not Matched"))
```

Comment: You have wrong brackets and `is null` shoudl be replaced with .isNull :
`.withColumn("Result", when(table("name") === table("name") || (table("name").isNull && table("name")).isNull," matched").otherwise(" Not Matched"))`

Comment: cannot resolve '((`name` IS NULL) AND `name`)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '((`name` IS NULL) AND `name`)' (boolean and string). I Tried but got this error.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `)` before `matched` value.

Try below code.

```
df1.join(df2,df2("id") === df2("id"))
.withColumn("Result", when((df1("name") === df2("name") || (df1("name").isNull && df2("name").isNull)),"matched").otherwise(" Not Matched"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting the same column from df2 in a join condition? Since the column name is same on both the dataframes, you can just put the column name in join condition.
Can you please try to change the code-
Your code-

```
     df1.join(df2,df2("id") === df2("id"))
     .withColumn("Result", when(df1("name") === df2("name") ||
     (df1("name") is null && 
     (df2("name") is null," matched"))
     .otherwise(" Not Matched"))
```

Change to-
df2("id") === df2("id") to "id"

```
// df2("id") === df2("id") 
df1.join(df2, "id")
.withColumn("Result", when((df1("name") === df2("name") || (df1("name").isNull && df2("name").isNull)),"matched").otherwise(" Not Matched"))
```

Haven't tested this but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`df1("name") is null` is not the function that you need, `is` is a method for any object in scala, you were looking for `df1("name") isNull` that will return a column reference class, that will have the `&&` method.

But looking the code, I will suggest using a null safe operator as `<=>` in your case, it will simplify your logic:

```
val NullVal = null.asInstanceOf[String]
List(
  ("hi" , "hi"),
  (NullVal, "hi"),
  (NullVal, NullVal)
).toDF("c1","c2")
.select($"c1", $"c2", $"c1" === $"c2", $"c1" <=> $"c2")
.show(false)
```

The result will be

```
+----+----+---------+-----------+
|c1  |c2  |(c1 = c2)|(c1 <=> c2)|
+----+----+---------+-----------+
|hi  |hi  |true     |true       |
|null|hi  |null     |false      |
|null|null|null     |true       |
+----+----+---------+-----------+
```